# How to reference the current user logged in MVC 4 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know if getting the current user logged in, including *ALL* it's attributes to store in session (during login) would be a good idea.

SimpleMembership has been left pretty much stock. How I can call the user object to grab from the `UserProfile` table.

I didn't see the Login controller create a `UserProfile` object to store the current user. Is there any slick method with EF api to do this?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.AspNet.Providers for membership,roles and user profile ?

Comment: If that's what the default bundle in MVC4 is called, then yes

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User ?

Comment: @ChrisTinsley Can you show an example of how HttpContext.Current.User is used?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api this article may be of use to you.  It's what I've used to get the User details (HttpContext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

...

User.Identity.Name
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

I think this will help you !!!!

Comment: Cannot import Microsoft.AspNet `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) `

Comment: Check whether this dll is added as reference or not "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll"

Comment: I believe User.Indentity is part of System.Web.Http in MVC 4

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can get a user object, and go through it's attributes

```
using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
{
     ctx.UserProfiles.Find(userID).ALL-ATTRIBUTES-HERE;
}
```

Comment: This however, will not return the user object as the OP asked for